# Networking on a PC, want to send data from one interface to another over the network

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, ip

If i have two network interface cars on my pc, like a wireless and LAN and i want to send data from wireless to LAN over the network, then tell me how can i do it.

I think i have to do something with `route print` commands or something.

I want to know how to do this so that they are actually send over the network and not locally transferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the network and sharing center, go to change adaptor settings, select both network cards, then right click on one of them and click bridge connections

Comment: If the WLAN has a separate network address to the wired LAN, won't Sara need routing not bridging?

Comment: you are right @RedGrittyBrick, it was a totally wrong answer but i selected in order to get myself some points